# Passing datas from controller to DAL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I created a web method where it will take parameters like this

```
public HttpResponseMessage  MakeOrders([FromUri] int[] orderId)
{
}
```

for which the request will be like this

```
http://www.test.com/MakeOrders?orderId=1&orderId=2
```

I need to pass these `orderId's` to `DAL`. So i have 2 questions

1. `[FromUri]` Is this the proper implementation or is this the standard way of practice for passing array values in query string?
2. Do i need to loop `orderId's` and pass to DAL as a single element so that i can make my DAL like this

DAL

```
public void UpdateOrder(int OrderId)
{
   var query = 'Update tbl SET isApproved=1 WHERE OrderId=@orderid'; 
}
```

or do i need to send as a array like this

```
public void UpdateOrder(int[] OrderId)
{
   var query = 'Update tbl SET isApproved=1 WHERE OrderId in (@orderid)'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The First Answer is:
I thought the better way to do is to pass List in json format

For example:

```
// Json format

var a=[1,2,3];
```

Pass this value using $.ajax() method of jquery.

Second answer would be:

```
public void UpdateOrder(int[] OrderId)
{
   var orderids= string.Join(",", (string[])OrderId.ToArray(Type.GetType("System.String")))
   var query = 'Update tbl SET isApproved=1 WHERE OrderId in (@orderids)'; 
}
```